# DELPHI + TWEbbrowser - append Option(s) and VALUE(s) into an Existing SELECT

Tags: delphi

On a webpage I have an empty select box:

```
<select id="select" >
</select>
```

From my Delphi (7 enterprise / XP - sp(3) ) I want to put N  OPTION(s) and VALUE(s) into that select.

N is fetched from a server and can be any number between 1 and 150:

something like this:

Only at runtime will I know the precise valyue of N (which might change from run to run  - here n = 5):

```
DELPHI:

For N := 0 to 5 DO
   PutIntoSelect('option' + inttostr(n), 'value' + inttostr(n));
```

so the result will be:

```
HTML:

    <select id="select" >
    <option = '0'>value0</option>
    <option = '1'>value1</option>
    <option = '2'>value2</option>
    <option = '3'>value3</option>
    <option = '4'>value4</option>
    <option = '5'>value5</option>
    </select>
```

How do I do that ?

I have studied IHTMLSELECTelement but I can't find something useful.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple. You just get an option element factory and call [**create**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa769141(v=vs.85).aspx) to instantiate a new option. The returned option you then add by the [**add**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768859(v=vs.85).aspx) method of your select element.

This code shows how, but **it's not safe**! You should crack it into pieces, and whenever you ask for reference, check if the asked one is assigned, so **take the following as an example of principle**:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Option: IHTMLOptionElement;
  Select: IHTMLSelectElement;
  Factory: IHTMLOptionElementFactory;
begin
  Select := (WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument3).getElementById('select') as IHTMLSelectElement;
  Factory := (WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2).parentWindow.Option;

  Option := Factory.create('Option 1', 'Value 1', False, True);
  Select.add(IHTMLElement(Option), Unassigned);
  Option := Factory.create('Option 2', 'Value 2', False, False);
  Select.add(IHTMLElement(Option), Unassigned);
end;
```

HTML you can play with:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <select id="select"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Anyway, 150 items in a combo box is almost for hiring a secretary :)

Comment: Thanks for the code. I'll try it and (eventuelly) modify it - if necessary.   _ About the 150 items:  (HEHE)   Yes, but (luckily)  the secretary will be off duty most of the time as the select will only at very rare situation contain 150 items (mostly 10 to 50 )  ..  Thanks for the Code again.

Comment: Then it needs one more combo with fixed count of items for keeping them busy :) I've tested this in Tokyo.

Comment: I hav now tested the code - carefully - everything worksand I am very satisfied. Again : For N := 0 to 100000000000000 DO  ShowMessage(' THANKS FOR THE CODE' ); + :)  :) :)